# Visual Studio keeps using wWinMain() as the entry point instead of the main() function I want it to

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, glfw

I started my Visual Studio project as a windows application, however I've come to realize that if I want to use GLFW then I'm supposed to open a GLFW window instead of a standard wWinMain window. I have a wWinMain function but since it kept running every time I ran the program instead of my `int main()` function with the GLFW window test code inside, I changed the name of the wWinMain function in the hopes that when building the program it would defer to the main() function I wrote. However it hasn't worked and instead I keep getting the same error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)`

How do I get it to stop looking for the wWinMain function and just run the main() one instead?

The only solution that has worked so far is to rename my main() function to wWinMain and have it accept all the variables but do nothing with them and just run my code as normal inside, however this doesn't seem optimal.

I've also tried the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342388/how-to-force-the-visual-studio-to-use-the-wmain-instead-of-main) but that always opens a command window with the GLFW window whereas with the wWinMain function by default would run without one except when I specifically used AllocConsole(), so I suspect the answer suggested there isn't actually the correct solution for my issue.

Ive also tried the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625905/my-app-wont-run-unless-i-declare-main-as-wmain-why-is-that-visual-studio-19) but that just doesn't work for me? idk maybe I'm implementing it wrong

Comment: `wWinMain` doesn't have to create any WIN32 windows.  If it's doing so then there must be some code in there to do it and you can just take it out.  Then do whatever GLFW magic you have in mind instead.

Comment: @PaulSanders no I know why wWinMain is opening the console (I have an AllocConsole call within the wWinMain function), the issue is that the console opens even when wWinMain *isn't called* which I believe as indicative of some issue with that solution or my implementation

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a "Windows Desktop Application" project rather than a "Console App" project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows knows two types of program that are relevant to you: Console and graphical.

Console programs automatically get a console (and you can get their output in a command line, for example) and their entry point is `main` or `wmain`.

Graphical programs don't get a console automatically, which is what you want. They don't automatically create any windows either; you'll have to do that manually (i.e. with GLFW like you want to). Their entry point is *always* `WinMain` or `wWinMain`.

You'll have to choose one, you can't mix-and-match. Just put your GLFW code in `wWinMain`. `main` is meaningless in a graphical Windows program, you should remove it. There's nothing wrong with not using the parameters passed to `wWinMain` - if you don't need them, that's fine. `main` also takes parameters that you don't currently use (but `main` is a little special since you can omit the unused parameters).

Comment: To be pedantic; WinMain is not the the PE entry point. The real entry point calls your WinMain function after it has initialized your globals etc.

Comment: As always, Raymond Chen has this covered: See [The name WinMain is just a convention](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061204-01/?p=28853) and [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573).

Answer (score 3):

The choice of main or winMain is controlled in the linker section of the project

[image]

- Subsystem = Console means main
- Subsystem = windows means winmain

Comment: And of course whether you get the regular entry point or the `w` version depends on if you've selected the Ansi character set or Unicode.  I definitely recommend Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add

```
int WinMain() {
    return main();
}
```

after your `main()` function. This way, if you switch between the Windows subsystem and the Console subsystem, it will work both ways.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to ever call `main` directly in C++; this can only ever be called safely by the operating system.

Comment: If you had the Windows SubSystem enabled, WinMain would be the main function instead of main()

Comment: That doesn't stop it from being undefined behavior as is specified in the C++ standard. The compiler can legally optimize out the whole call to `main` because it's simply not legal to make that call, ever. The calling convention to `main` is not standardized; only the implementation knows how to do that. There's no guarantee that it will be the same as a normal function.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh ok